# Java nested for loop print out

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I'm a total beginner to java and need help writing this nested for loop. This is the desired output.

```
2     3      5
5     10     26
11    31     131
23    94     656
```

I understand that the increment is 2 times the first number + 1, but I don't understand how to create the loop for it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {   
        for(int j = i; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+(i*j));
        }   
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. It will help if you have a specific question - what have you tried so far and what errors do you see?

Comment: I understand how to create the loops but I just cant figure out how to get the increments right to print it down and across.

Comment: could you please share your code.. so that we can help you

Comment: How about the first row - is it fixed (just three numbers: 2, 3, 5), or is there any rule for it?

Comment: no rules just needs to print to the console exactly how it is

Comment: I see, please see my answer for your reference, thanks :-)

Comment: @Johnathan please look at the below post code by me. please accept answer  if this is what your needs..

Comment: Thank you all I appreciate the responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code (I have tested the code, the output is exactly the same as yours):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[][] results = new int[4][3];
    results[0][0] = 2;
    results[0][1] = 3;
    results[0][2] = 5;

    for (int i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < results[0].length; j++) {
            results[i][j] = results[i - 1][j] * results[0][j] + 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < results[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(results[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Question is so simple it consists of two things read the pattern and use the appropriate loop statements in java to achieve this. Printing them is another task which is not difficult.
@Jonathan your pattern is right but your algorithm is incorrect.
I'm not giving you perfect solution but you have to use proper loop statement to make it efficient. I'm here giving you a thought so that you can think in this way..hope you get it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
/*  2     3      5
    5     10     26
    11    31     131
    23    94     656
*/
    int two = 2;
    int three = 3;
    int five = 5;
    int i=0;
     //use do-while to print 2 3 5
        do{
            System.out.println(two +"  "+ three +"  "+five);
            two=two*2+1; // apply math pattern
            three= three*3+1;
            five= five*5+1;

            i++;
        }while(i<4);;

}
```